# Make anaconda jupyter notebook auto save .py script

Tags: python

I would like to simply be able to launch the jupyter notebook from Anaconda and have it automatically save a .py script when I save the .ipynb. I tried modifying the `jupyter-notebook-script.py` in the Anaconda3/envs/env_name/Scripts/ but that wasn't the right way. I know I want to set the `post-save-hook=True` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the Anaconda3\envs\env_name\etc\jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json by adding

```
"FileContentsManager": {
    "post-save-hook":true
}
```